# Image viewer with pagination is extremely slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, state

I have a React component that displays a grid of images. The grid:

- Must offer pagination. (Display batches of 150 images, allowing to go to the next and previous 150 images).
- Must allow the selection of images (Single selection by just clicking, multiple single selection by holding the **ctrl** key when clicking, and multiple adyacent selection by holding the **shift** key when clicking.
- The selection must be along all of the files, not just the ones being displayed.

The problem that I'm facing is that the image selection is highly inneficient. If you click an image, sometimes it can take up to 3-4 seconds to be selected. So either the `handleClickOnGridItem` function is super inneficient or something weird is happening.

**If the cause of the problem is indeed the inefficiency of the function I'll be really grateful if you could provide a solution that meets the requirements and does not cause the problem that I'm having.**

If you go to [the CodeSandbox MRE](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/image-viewer-with-pagination-and-selection-2ekveb) you will see what I'm talking about. **Try it uploading 500 images or more and you will see**.

Here's my component:

```
import {
  useState,
  useMemo,
  ChangeEvent,
  CSSProperties,
  MouseEvent,
} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedFilenames, setSelectedFilenames] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const imagesPerPage = 150;

  const endIndex = useMemo(() => {
    return Math.min(startIndex + imagesPerPage, files.length);
  }, [files, startIndex]);

  const displayedFiles = useMemo(() => {
    return files.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  }, [files, startIndex]);

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    if (startIndex - imagesPerPage >= 0) {
      setStartIndex(startIndex - imagesPerPage);
    }
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    if (endIndex < files.length) {
      setStartIndex(startIndex + imagesPerPage);
    }
  };

  const handleFileInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newFiles = Array.from(e.target.files!);
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };

  const handleClickOnGridItem = (
    i: number,
    e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
      setSelectedFilenames((prevSelectedFilenames) => {
        if (prevSelectedFilenames.includes(displayedFiles[i].name)) {
          return prevSelectedFilenames.filter(
            (name) => name !== displayedFiles[i].name
          );
        } else {
          return [...prevSelectedFilenames, displayedFiles[i].name];
        }
      });
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
      if (selectedFilenames.length === 0) {
        const range = [0, i].sort((a, b) => a - b);
        const newSelectedFilenames = displayedFiles
          .slice(range[0], range[1] + 1)
          .map((file) => file.name);
        setSelectedFilenames(newSelectedFilenames);
      } else if (selectedFilenames.length > 0) {
        const firstIndex = displayedFiles.findIndex(
          (file) => file.name === selectedFilenames[0]
        );
        const range = [firstIndex, i].sort((a, b) => a - b);
        const newSelectedFilenames = displayedFiles
          .slice(range[0], range[1] + 1)
          .map((file) => file.name);
        setSelectedFilenames(newSelectedFilenames);
      }
    } else {
      setSelectedFilenames([displayedFiles[i].name]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <input
        type='file'
        className='mt-3'
        id='singleFileInput'
        title='Upload an image'
        accept='image/*'
        multiple
        onChange={handleFileInputChange}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'evenly',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: '25vw',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={handlePrevClick}> Prev </button>
        <button onClick={handleNextClick}> Next </button>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
      >
        {displayedFiles.map((file, i) => {
          const isSelected = selectedFilenames.includes(file.name);
          const maxHeight = 80;
          const margin = 2;
          const imgStyle: CSSProperties = isSelected
            ? {
                marginLeft: margin,
                marginTop: margin,
                maxHeight,
                opacity: 1,
              }
            : {
                marginLeft: margin,
                marginTop: margin,
                maxHeight,
                opacity: 0.5,
              };

          return (
            <img
              style={imgStyle}
              src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
              onClick={(e) => handleClickOnGridItem(i, e)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the inefficiency of the `handleClickOnGridItem` function. The problem is that I'm generating every image url on each render inside the `return` scope of the component. Now, I'm generating the list of image urls when the user uploads it's files, and it works now super fast with 0 lag.

Here's the super efficient code :

```
import {
  useState,
  useMemo,
  ChangeEvent,
  CSSProperties,
  MouseEvent,
} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedUrls, setSelectedUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const imagesPerPage = 150;

  const endIndex = useMemo(() => {
    return Math.min(startIndex + imagesPerPage, urls.length);
  }, [urls, startIndex]);

  const displayedUrls = useMemo(() => {
    return urls.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  }, [urls, startIndex]);

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    if (startIndex - imagesPerPage >= 0) {
      setStartIndex(startIndex - imagesPerPage);
    }
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    if (endIndex < urls.length) {
      setStartIndex(startIndex + imagesPerPage);
    }
  };

  const handleFileInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newFiles = Array.from(e.target.files!);
    setUrls(newFiles.map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file)));
  };

  const handleClickOnGridItem = (
    i: number,
    e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
      setSelectedUrls((prevUrls) => {
        if (prevUrls.includes(displayedUrls[i])) {
          return prevUrls.filter((url) => url !== displayedUrls[i]);
        } else {
          return [...prevUrls, displayedUrls[i]];
        }
      });
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
      if (selectedUrls.length === 0) {
        const range = [0, i].sort((a, b) => a - b);
        const newUrls = displayedUrls
          .slice(range[0], range[1] + 1)
          .map((url) => url);
        setSelectedUrls(newUrls);
      } else if (selectedUrls.length > 0) {
        const firstIndex = displayedUrls.findIndex(
          (url) => url === selectedUrls[0]
        );
        const range = [firstIndex, i].sort((a, b) => a - b);
        const newUrls = displayedUrls
          .slice(range[0], range[1] + 1)
          .map((url) => url);
        setSelectedUrls(newUrls);
      }
    } else {
      setSelectedUrls([displayedUrls[i]]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <input
        type='file'
        className='mt-3'
        id='singleFileInput'
        title='Upload an image'
        accept='image/*'
        multiple
        onChange={handleFileInputChange}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'evenly',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: '25vw',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={handlePrevClick}> Prev </button>
        <button onClick={handleNextClick}> Next </button>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
      >
        {displayedUrls.map((url, i) => {
          const isSelected = selectedUrls.includes(url);
          const maxHeight = 80;
          const margin = 2;
          const imgStyle: CSSProperties = isSelected
            ? {
                marginLeft: margin,
                marginTop: margin,
                maxHeight,
                opacity: 1,
              }
            : {
                marginLeft: margin,
                marginTop: margin,
                maxHeight,
                opacity: 0.25,
              };

          return (
            <img
              style={imgStyle}
              src={url}
              onClick={(e) => handleClickOnGridItem(i, e)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```